# How can I solve Multiple precompiled assemblies with the same name websocket-sharp.dll

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-streaming, photon

Multiple precompiled assemblies with the same name websocket-sharp.dll included or the current platform. Only one assembly with the same name is allowed per platform.

I use photon pun2 to accomplish the multiple player game, and I want to use unity video streaming to share my video, but there are two  websocket-sharp.dll documents, how can I fix this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

websocket-sharp is a very common library. In general, you can simply remove the older version of websocket-sharp for fixing the duplication error.